# Temp Table with random NEWID columns T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am looking for a solution to create a temporary table we can use for data scrambling purposes.  The first column would contain a user id order by id desc and each additional column would be the values from the first column ordered by NEWID().  Here is an example:

```
| ID    | RandomID1     | RandomID2     | RandomID3     |
|:--:   |:---------:    |:---------:    |:---------:    |
|  12   |     25        |     50        |     48        |
|  25   |     48        |     12        |     36        |
|  36   |     36        |     36        |     12        |
|  48   |     50        |     48        |     50        |
|  50   |     12        |     25        |     25        |
```

My current work around is manually create these one column at a time and paste into .csv and then import that into a temp table.

If would be nice to supply a value for the amount of extra random columns but if not, a fixed number of 3 extra columns will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for permutations.  If the numbers start at 1 and are gapless, you can just use `row_number()`:

```
select id,
       row_number() over (order by newid()) as randomid1,
       row_number() over (order by newid()) as randomid2,
       row_number() over (order by newid()) as randomid3
from t;
```

If the ids do not meet this condition, you can generate the random permutations and then `join` in the original ids for the permutation.

Comment: I cannot use row_number because there are gaps and the ID's do not always start at 1.  Can you supply some sample syntax for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

what I use to generate a random number is here, this is for 1 to 100. using newid()

```
select 1+abs(checksum(newid()))%100 -- returns a number under 100 starting at 1, if the 1 becomes 50 then a number between 50 and 150
```